# Jsoup- conditional select

Tags: html, jsoup

I have a requirement wherein I need to fetch tr from doc by passing specific th and its corresponding td value using jsoup. I can fetch individual td and th using contains(). But is there a way I can test whether any particular td value corresponds to that th. e.g. I have below html

```
<tr>
<th>id</th>
<th>name</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>11</td>
<td>ABC</td>
</tr>
```

Here I need to find tr based on 2 arguments- th and td. say if I pass name and ABC, it should fetch me complete tr. if I pass arguments pair that do not match i.e. name and DEF, it should not return tr as name col doesn't have DEF value .

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the `Node#siblingIndex()` method.

First, we'll determine the sibling index of the `th` element matching "*name*".
Finding this `th` is done with the CSS selector below:

```
th:containsOwn(thValue)
```

Then we look for a `tr` element having a `td` element with the same sibling index and containing the value "*ABC*". This is resumed with the following CSS selector:

```
table tr:has(td:containsOwn(tdValue):eq(thSiblingIndex))
```

#### Java Code

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;

/**
 * 
 * Returns the first tr element with all following requirements:
 *    - Has a th element with own text containing thValue
 *    - Has a td element with own text containing tdValue
 *    - The matching th and td elements msut have the same sibling index.
 * 
 * @param doc The document to search in
 * @param thValue The value in the th element
 * @param tdValue The value in the td element
 * @return The first matching tr element.
 * @throws RuntimeException if no tr element can be found.
 * 
 */
public static Element findFirstTR(Document doc, String thValue, String tdValue) {
    Element th = doc.select("th:containsOwn(" + thValue + ")").first();
    if (th == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Unable to find th element containing: " + thValue);
    }

    Element tr = th.parents().select("table tr:has(td:containsOwn(" + tdValue + "):eq(" + th.siblingIndex() + "))").first();
    if (tr == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Unable to find tr element matching: thValue=" + thValue + " and tdValue=" + tdValue);
    }

    return tr;
}
```

#### SAMPLE CODE

```
String html = "<table><tr><th>id</th><th>name</th></tr><tr><td>11</td><td>ABC</td></tr></table>";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Element tr = findFirstTR(doc, "name", "ABC");

System.out.println(tr.outerHtml());
```

#### OUTPUT

```
<tr>
 <td>11</td>
 <td>ABC</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks Stephan. With this I am able to get first match between th and td. But say, i have same more tables in the document and they also contain same column "name" and in case any of those columns contain ABC, result should fetch <tr>s for all those matches. Can we achieve this?

Comment: @user4067046 See JonasCz answer.

Answer (score 1):

After a little bit of experimenting, I came up with this; it finds the element with the specified text in the table header (`th`), and if it exists and the other specified text exists in the right place inside the table, returns the entire table row.

```
private Elements fetchCompleteTr (Document doc, String tableHeaderName, String tableValue) {
    Elements tableHeaders = doc.select("th:containsOwn(" + tableHeaderName + ")"); //find the table header
    if (tableHeaders.isEmpty()) {
        return null; //the header was not found in the table
    }

    int thElementIndex = tableHeaders.first().elementSiblingIndex();
    Elements tableRows = doc.select("tr:has(td:eq(" + thElementIndex + "):containsOwn(" + tableValue + "))");

    if (tableRows.isEmpty()) {
        return null;  //the value for the specified table header does not exist.
    } else {
        return tableRows;
    }
}
```

Here's a test and a bit of a demo on how to use it:

```
System.out.println("With fetchCompleteTr, \"name\", \"ABC\"):");
System.out.println(fetchCompleteTr(doc, "name", "ABC"));

System.out.println("With fetchCompleteTr(doc, \"name\", \"XYZ\"):");
System.out.println(fetchCompleteTr(doc, "name", "XYZ"));

System.out.println("With fetchCompleteTr(doc, \"id\", \"11\"):");
System.out.println(fetchCompleteTr(doc, "id", "11") );
```

Which prints:

```
With fetchCompleteTr(doc, "name", "ABC"):
<tr>
  <td>11</td>
  <td>ABC</td>
</tr>

With fetchCompleteTr(doc, "name", "XYZ"):
null (because no "name" with "XYZ" in the table exists)

With fetchCompleteTr(doc, "id", "11"):
<tr>
  <td>11</td>
  <td>ABC</td>
</tr>
```

---

If you want to use this with multiple tables, you can modify it like like this:

```
private Elements fetchCompleteTr (Element table, String tableHeaderName, String tableValue) {
Elements tableHeaders = table.select("th:containsOwn(" + tableHeaderName + ")"); //find the table header
    if (tableHeaders.isEmpty()) {
        return null; //the header was not found in the table
    }

    int thElementIndex = tableHeaders.first().elementSiblingIndex();
    Elements tableRows = table.select("tr:has(td:eq(" + thElementIndex + "):containsOwn(" + tableValue + "))");

    if (tableRows.isEmpty()) {
        return null;  //the value for the specified table header does not exist.
    } else {
        return tableRows;
    }
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
for (Element e: myDocument.select("table")) {
    With fetchCompleteTr(e, "name", "XYZ");
}
```

This way you can search all the tables in the document.

---

Note that I haven't tested this extensively so may contain bugs. It also seems quite complicated, but I couldn't think of anything shorter / better.

Comment: Thanks JonasCz. With this I am able to get first match between th and td. But say, i have same more tables in the document and they also contain same column "name" and in case any of those columns contain ABC, result should fetch <tr>s for all those matches. Can we achieve this?

Comment: @user4067046, I've updated my answer with details on how you can apply this with multiple tables in your document. I've also modified it to return all the found rows of the table instead of just the first. Check my edit.

Comment: Hi JonasCz, thanks for your help. I have another requirement that in case i want to pass another pair of arguments : columnname and its value, it should fetch subset from above returned result. Say if first argument match returned 4 rows and i pass another pair of arguments to the program, it searches for the argument pair in the first result and returns matching rows - kind of AND logic for first and second pair of arguments.

Comment: @user4067046, I'll have a look, an I'll update my answer.